# How to cast object from C# in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a class library project in Visual Basic with a class like:

```vb
Public Class Test
    Public Vaule As Integer
    Public Str As String
    .
    .
    .
End Class
```

And a Function which gets an object from C#.
How to cast the object from C# in Visual Basic?
Neither `DirectCast` nor `CType` work.

```vb
Public Class Calculate
    Public Function CalculateTest(test As Object)
        Dim t As Test = New Test
        Dim tt = DirectCast(test, Test) '(Ctype do not work either)
        t.Vaule = tt.Vaule * 2
        t.Str = "Hello " + tt.Str
        Return t
    End Function
End Class
```

Code in C# (the DLL from the class library project in Visual Basic is as reference):

```
    public class Test
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Str { get; set; }
        .
        .
    }

   public SubmitData()
    {
         Calculate cal = new Calculate();

        Test t = new Test() { Value = 4, Str = "Johan" };

        Object obj = cal.CalculateTest(t);
       .
       .
   }
```

Comment: The original language doesn't matter. You'd have the *same* problem if that library was built using VB.NET - the types aren't the same. You can't cast one type to another just because they have the same name. Why declare a `Test` class in the VB.NET project at all?

Comment: BTW the two types don't even look the same. One uses properties, the other uses public fields. I suspect the *real* problem is that `test` is passed as an Object without good reason. Why not just pass it using the *correct* type? You won't need to cast anything then

Comment: And `Vaule` is spelt differently.

Comment: *Type identity* is an important aspect of .NET.  The type isn't just identified by namespace+class name, which assembly it came from counts as well.  It is a very important DLL Hell counter-measure.  So two different assemblies here, completely unrelated types with no way to cast.  Imagine what would happen if it didn't work that way and you'd make a change in the C# definition of the class.  The workaround is simple, just have the C# code use the VB.NET version of the class.  It is already Public so no problemo.

Comment: If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to create the Test object in your vb.net project unless it will encapsulate new functionalities and features. If this is the case then consider subclassing. Otherwise, you already have the object created in the c# project.
2. In your vb.net code, you are trying to cast from and to unrelated objects. You can do that only if the vb.net Test object inherits the c# Test object. Nonetheless, consider specifying the full namespace of the target object if you insist to use identical objects names. Better to rename the Test object in your active project to something else to avoid the ambiguous-exceptions.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You shouldnt cast the object, but recreate an object with an embedded class with all primitive member.

In your case it could be simpler to implement some function with more parameters.

Always remember: the cast will give you access to memory of a different runtime. And so provide some strange behaviour.